# Certificate to be used for encryption in iOS MDM

Tags: c#, ios, certificate, mdm

I am facing issue in encrypting the final configuration profile to be sent to the iOS device(Phase 3).

I am using the Bouncy castle library to encrypt my final profile(http://elian.co.uk/post/2009/07/29/Bouncy-Castle-CSharp.aspx).

**Questions:**

1. Which certificate should I use for encrypting the profile,
   Is it a CA or Server certificate created or  Certificate returned after Phase 2(SCEP)?

A code sample would be very helpful.

**NOTE:** The profile is getting installed successfully without encryption or even if I sign the profile.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you always

- encrypt using device identity cert (which is generated through SCEP or PKCS12)
- sign using Server certificate

Comment: It might be more clear to say 'encrypt using device identity cert...' Just a thought.

Comment: I was trying to retrieve Public Key from the Identity certificate as below:                                                            var publikKey = cerificate.GetPublicKeyString();                    I feeded it to Bouncy Castle . Exception is thrown saying : Key length not 128/192/256 bits. Am I doing some thing wrong here?? Do I need to convert public key into 128 byte string by some way??

Comment: @user170940: I would recommend to take a look on OS X Server MDM implementation. Generally speaking to encrypt profile, as I remember you should use PKCS7 wrapping. So, you should look at this: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/jce/PKCS7SignedData.html BTW. I would recommend to read up a little bit on cryptography, if you want to get general understanding. Very-very high level overview of your problem: you are trying to use RSA key directly to encrypt the data. However, it should be used to encrypt a symmetric key which in its turn is used to encrypt the data.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be CMSAlgorithm.DES_EDE3_CBC encrypted from the identity certificate and Base64 encode the result. That result needs to be signed as you did in the previous stage.